# How to remove a span element temporarily when looping through a list?

Tags: javascript, html, for-loop, html-lists, window.open

I wrote a little program where you enter links into several lists. Created a button that when clicked opens all the links in that specific list. But the problem encountered was that, when it loops through the list to open the link it took the span element into account (And also just opens the first link in the list).

I added a span at the end of every list element to act as a delete button for that specific list element.
So if the link is for example `https://www.youtube.com` it shows it as `https://www.youtube.com/x`, adding the `<span>`'s content also.

I have tried removing the span in the loop but then it won't open the links anymore.

Does anyone have any advice for me, I would greatly appreciate it.

*Creating the list*

```
if (inputBox2.value === "python") {
  let li = document.createElement("li");
  let a = inputBox.value;
  li.innerHTML = inputBox.value.link(a);
  listContainer.appendChild(li);
  let span = document.createElement("span");
  span.innerHTML = "\u00d7";
  li.appendChild(span);
}
```

*Opening the links*

```
var option = listContainer.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (var i = 0; i < option.length; i++) {
  window.open(option[0].innerText,'_blank','location=0');
}
```

I tried to remove the span element temporarily in the function that opens the links but then it won't work at all. I get no errors it just would not work.

I also tried to work around the span by finding another method to delete the list items but all I can think of is maybe adding a button that deletes based on the position of the list item, like li[0].

Answer (score 0):

So in your case, it is best to just put the link also in a separate tag as follows:

```js
const allLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".link")

function openLinks() {
  allLinks.forEach(element => setTimeout(() => window.open(element.innerText, Math.random().toString(), "_blank"), 500))
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span class="link">https://youtube.com</span><span>x</span></li>
  <li><span class="link">https://google.com</span><span>x</span></li>
  <li><span class="link">https://facebook.com</span><span>x</span></li>
</ul>

<button onClick="openLinks();">Open all links</button>
```

Keep in mind that Chrome will block everything after the first opened link so you need to allow that from the settings of the website (Look [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSoCb.png))

*It will not work here in the code snippet for obvious reasons*